# Query both sides of a friend relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have my Postgres table set up as such:

```
CREATE TABLE "Friendships" (
    id integer DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY,
    "fromUserId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users"(id),
    "toUserId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users"(id)
);
```

When a user fetches their friendships, I run: `SELECT * FROM Friendships WHERE fromUserId=XXXX`.

How do I modify the query so that additional data is added to the results (true/false) based on whether `toUserId` also added that user?

Example result:

`[
    { id: 444, fromUserId: 1, toUserId: 22, addedBack: false },
    { id: 445, fromUserId: 1, toUserId: 67, addedBack: true },
    { id: 446, fromUserId: 1, toUserId: 599, addedBack: true },
    { id: 447, fromUserId: 1, toUserId: 733, addedBack: false },
]`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: What you mean by describing `addedBack` column is not comprehensible through your shared data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select f.*,
  exists (
    select 0 from "Friendships"
    where "toUserId" = f."fromUserId" and "fromUserId" = f."toUserId"
  ) addedBack
from "Friendships" f
where f."fromUserId" = 1
```

For this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO "Friendships"(id, "fromUserId", "toUserId") VALUES
(444, 1, 22), (445, 1, 67), (446, 1, 599), (447, 1, 733), 
(448, 67, 1), (449, 599, 1);
```

Results:

```
>  id | fromUserId | toUserId | addedback
> --: | ---------: | -------: | :--------
> 444 |          1 |       22 | f        
> 445 |          1 |       67 | t        
> 446 |          1 |      599 | t        
> 447 |          1 |      733 | f
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=3e43e9aa65bcbd1237d71e2d9fc31b84).

Comment: Thanks! How would I modify your query so that instead of returning true/false, it returns the *id* of the addedBack row?

Comment: @TIMEX . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not *comments*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left outer join to check for the reciprocate value:

```
select
  f.id,
  f.fromuserid,
  f.touserid,
  case when r.id is null then false else true end as addedback
from friendships f
left join friendships r on f.touserid = r.fromuserid 
                       and r.touserid = f.fromuserid 
where f.fromuserid = XXXX
```